Error in .tscn file: "scene/main/node.cpp:1311 - Condition "name.is_empty()" is true." all the nodes in my scene has desapeared
I have been working on this intr scene for a month now. It is basically a dialogue animated scene. It was finished a few days ago, and when I open it again it gives me this error in the output:

scene/main/node.cpp:1311 - Condition "name.is_empty()" is true.

The scene appears with a red X and all the nodes inside are gone.
The yellow triangle message says this in a floating window:


This node was saved as class type 'Object', which was no longer available when this scene was loaded.
Data from the original node is kept as a placeholder until this type of node is available again. It can hence be safely re-saved without
risk data loss.


The original node was a Node2Dwith a script attached, the most of the things happened in the script and the AnimationPlayer node.
I did my research and find that the name of the node could be lost so I had to open the .tscn file in the txt editor and find the line with the name missing and put a name. So I did that and the .txt file has only 2 lines of code, all the data of the node tree is not there:
[gd_scene format=3 uid="uid://bhnswaw6nk3t8"]


[node name="intro" type="Object"]

I just added the name value.
If that's a placeholder as the message says: How can I recover all the data of the scene? How can I solve this error and recover the finished scene?
Please help!

I imagine it wasn't in version control since you are asking. So, perhaps some tool to recover deleted files could work. But as time passes that is less likely to work, so at this point I do not expect it to.
